# Split large CSV into multiple files small csv by group name and maintain output format

Tags: powershell, csv, split, output

I'm working as a printer admin, and I export many print reports. The report is exported in a large CSV. I managed to split that CSV by group name, the content is OK but it's not maintaining the same output format.

So there is this main file, and I split by groups, like this.

[image: How I split]

This is a good report, well exported:

[image: Good report]

If you see, it has a format, that contains `"` and `,`, but only where is needed.

When I split the CSV, with this command:

```
$fullpath = ".\Todos los dep_abr 24_mayo23_2018.csv"

$path = Split-Path $fullpath -Parent
$data = Import-Csv -Path $fullpath -Header "cGroupID", "cGroupIDBillable",
        "cGroupName", "cGroupDescription", "cRowName", "cRowDescription",
        "cRowID", "cDepartment", "cUnits", "cBWPages", "cColourPages",
        "cAmount", "cAltCost", "cJobs", "cBillable", "cLocation",
        "cBreakColumn"

foreach ($group in $data | Group cGroupName) {
    $data | Where-Object {$_.cGroupName -eq $group.name} |
        ConvertTo-csv -NoTypeInformation |
        Out-File -Encoding utf8 ".\TODOS LOS DEP24_ABR_23_MAYO_18\DEP\$($group.name).csv"
}
```

The output of the file, is like this, the bad report:

[image: bad report]

Could  you please help me, if you know a comand that will maintain the output format as it is in the main file, when split by the group.

I forgot to mention that i need this output to be like this, because after i got the report, i create a html report with a table in powershell also. So that´s why is very important to be the same output as the original. Thank you very much

The double " need to be only in , the places that need to be, as in the good code. If you watch the good report, there are " but only in a few spots.

The html table will generate wrong if the report is not as the good one.

Thank you very much.

---

UPDATE:

I FOUND A SCRIPT THAT DOES WHAT I NEED, MAINTAINS THE OUTPUT AS IT IS ON THE LARGE FILE, but it´s spliting by size not by group as in my own script. How can i modify this for my need.

```
$src = ".\Informe 3 meses actividad detallada usuarios.csv"
$SplitPath = ".\Informe 3 meses actividad detallada usuarios - {0}.csv"

$inData = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $src
$header = $inData.ReadLine()
$outData = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder
[void]$outData.Append($header)
$i = 0

while ( $line = $inData.ReadLine() ) {
    if ( $outData.Length -gt 200MB ) {
        $outData.ToString() | Out-File -FilePath ( $SplitPath -f $i ) -Encoding utf8
        $outData = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder
        [void]$outData.Append($header)
        $i++
    }
    Write-Verbose "$currentFile, $line"
    [void]$outData.Append("`r`n$($line)")
}

$outData.ToString() | Out-File -FilePath ( $SplitPath -f $i ) -Encoding utf8
```

This is working great, but it´s spliting by size, not by groups and the output is correct. Help please.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i need this output to be like this, because after i got the report, i create a html report with a table in powershell also. So that´s why is very important to be  the same output as the original. Thank you very much

Comment: the additional information you provided in your comment would be of more value if you edit your post and place it in the post itself.

Comment: If you want your bad report to look like your good report, why dont you try this-
`... Where-Object {$_.cGroupName -eq $group.name} |  % { if ($_ -match "\d+") {$_ -replace ('"', '')}} | ConvertTo-csv -NoTypeInformation ... `

Comment: What is the *problem*? The quoted values are still valid!

Comment: As gvee mentioned, double quotes around values in a CSV are perfectly valid and should be automatically removed by any proper CSV importer. Please explain why you think you need them removed.

Comment: The output has to be the same as in the good report, because the html table will not show the correct way. Also , the csv , when its opened in Excel, the fields are moving because of the " , but if you take a look, at the good report, there are only a few " that are allowed. So that´s is why i need to be the same.

Comment: Vivek Kumar Singh.. i´ve tried your modifcation , but it´s not working,is asking me for each input object.

Comment: I sense an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What does "the html table will not show the correct way" mean? What would be the actual output compared to the desired output? How are you creating the HTML in the first place?

Comment: The issue is not how i create the html report, and the table. The error is on the file , because i convert from csv , to an html table. So in order that the fields show the correct information, i need that the file source, be as the good report as shown up in my question. Because the good report, have the " where need to be, and the , also where is needed. I just need to split, the big report, and the output to be the same. I don´t know if this is possible. Let´s focus on just to split, without messing up with the format, please. Thank you guys

Comment: I can practically guarantee you that the issue is *exactly* with how you create that report.

Comment: It is not, because, the script that i´ve create do more steps, the first steps is the one that i need help to split correctly the file. i try spliting manually and it´s works properly. the second step, translate the csv header into spanish, the third one add a description on a third row, the 4th step create the html table, and then rename the file and send it with an sent message. the script goes perfectly if i split manually as in the good repot. that´s why i need to  split automaticaly and get the output right

Comment: I found a script that does what i need , an keeps the format, but it´s not spliting by group, it´s splitting by size. How can i modify this script to split by group as in my script above.  PLEASE SEE IT ABOVE IN THE DESCRIPTION.

Comment: *\*shrug\** Since you seem to know better how to solve the problem than the people you came to for help: don't let me stand in your way by trying to fix the actual problem rather than the symptom. Have fun.

Comment: I didn´t want to be disrespectful, I just know, that the issue lies within the report output, just that. Because all the other functions work well , once the report is the good one. it´s seems logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is solved.

I combined to scripts. First i used the script that split large files, the one for the large files that is up in the question.

As the script , was spliting good but by size, after the script ended i user my script to take out the groups and it worked.

I have the good reports by group and with the same output without the ".

For the record also i checked the html format and with the " for this report won´t worked, even if the delimiter was '"'. That´s why i need to be exact as the good report, the output.

I wish someone from here , helped me out to solve it , in just one powershell. But seems that nobody knows, a way to split without formating the output. Well no problem.

Thank you all for your sugestions. You are a great team. Thanks to stackoverflow too.